# Jquery append and remove element

Tags: jquery, append, removechild

I have a function to add elements to a table which is:

```
$('#mais').on('click', function(){
var next = $('#lista tbody').children('tr').length + 1;
$(':input[name="qtd_itens"]').val(next);
$('#lista tbody').append('<tr>' +
      '<td><input type="text" name="qtd' + next + '" size="5" /></td>' +
      '<td><input type="text" name="unidade' + next + '" size="6" /></td>' +
      '<td><input type="text" name="mercadoria' + next + '" size="20" /></td>' +
      '<td><input type="text" name="codigo' + next + '" size="15" /></td>' +
      '<td><input type="text" name="preco' + next + '" size="10" class="money" /></td>' +
      '<td><input type="text" name="total' + next + '" size="10" readonly /></td>' +
      '<th><a href="#" id="menos"><img src="imgs/delete.png" height="20px" width="20px"></a></th>' +
      '</tr>');     
$('.money').maskMoney({thousands:'.', decimal:','});
return false;
});
```

An i tried to do the remove function but i couldn't be able.

I have tried :

```
$('#menos').on('click', function(){
$('#lista tbody').children('tr:last').remove(); 
$(':input[name="qtd_itens"]').val() -= 1;
});
```

But it's not working. Can someone help?

Comment: `$(':input[name="qtd_itens"]').val() -= 1;` should be `$(':input[name="qtd_itens"]').val($('#lista tbody').children('tr').length);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to

- use `menos` as a class because it is repeated in every row
- use event delegation because the elements are created dynamically
- you need to delete the row whose delete button was clicked
- you cannot set a value to a function invocation as you have done in the delete method to set the value of the input

it should be

```
$('#mais').on('click', function () {
    var next = $('#lista tbody').children('tr').length + 1;
    $(':input[name="qtd_itens"]').val(next);
    $('#lista tbody').append('<tr>' +
        '<td><input type="text" name="qtd' + next + '" size="5" /></td>' +
        '<td><input type="text" name="unidade' + next + '" size="6" /></td>' +
        '<td><input type="text" name="mercadoria' + next + '" size="20" /></td>' +
        '<td><input type="text" name="codigo' + next + '" size="15" /></td>' +
        '<td><input type="text" name="preco' + next + '" size="10" class="money" /></td>' +
        '<td><input type="text" name="total' + next + '" size="10" readonly /></td>' +
        '<th><a href="#" class="menos"><img src="imgs/delete.png" height="20px" width="20px"></a></th>' +
        '</tr>');
    return false;
});
$('#lista').on('click', '.menos', function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    $(':input[name="qtd_itens"]').val(function (i, val) {
        val = +val;
        return val > 1 ? val - 1 : 0;
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kA7ps/)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Id 'menos', you need to apply it as class name like,

```
<th><a href="#" class="menos"><img src="imgs/delete.png" height="20px" width="20px"></a></th>
```

Then try,

```
$(document).on('click','.menos', function(){
$('#lista tbody').children('tr:last').remove(); 
$(':input[name="qtd_itens"]').val() -= 1;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rENjR/). The only main problem was the way you did the subtraction `$(':input[name="qtd_itens"]').val() -= 1;`.